# Sequelize creating a new database connection despite being passed in a transaction from a different connection

Tags: node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

Sequelize is creating a new database connection despite being passed in a transaction from a different connection. Take a look at the code below, and thank you in advance for all of your help!

```
const sequelize = Sequelize(dbConn);
const transaction = sequelize.transaction();
await sequelize.query(`SELECT 'test';` { transaction });  // Uses the connection associated with `const sequelize`
await sequelize.models.Patietnt.findAll({}, { transaction });  // Creates a new database connection despite being passed in a transaction from a different connection
await transaction.rollback();
await sequelize.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

`findAll` unlike `query` expects `transaction` option in the first parameter:

```js
await sequelize.models.Patietnt.findAll({ transaction });
```